# objects that are changed wont redraw

Tags: java, android

nevermind, i figured it out. i just derped pretty bad

this first part is in the onDraw method. it stores everything in the array correctly and draws them. when i call invalidate() and when i change a value in the object inside the array it still draws the objects original values.

```
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            if(once==false)
            {
                once=!once;

                for (int i = 0 ; i < xGrid ; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0 ; j < yGrid ; j++) {
                        //a bunch of objects (same kind) added to a 
                        //multidimentional array called gridTiles
                    }
                }

            }

            for(int x=0;x<8;x++)
            {
                for(int y=0;y<8;y++)
                {
                    gridTiles[x][y].draw(canvas);
                }
            }
```

this method is called from the onTouch method. basically what im trying to do is just switch the objects inside of the array

```
 public void moveBlockOnGrid()
        {
            int touchXGridStart,touchXGridEnd; //start is where you first press and end is where your finger is lifted
            int touchYGridStart,touchYGridEnd;

            if(touchYStart>intValue(ht / 3.5)&&touchYStart<intValue(ht / 3.5 + (patternW * 4)))
            {
                touchYGridStart=((touchYStart-intValue(ht / 3.5))/(patternW/2));
                touchXGridStart=touchXStart/(patternW/2);
                //touchYGridStart=((1150-intValue(1920 / 3.5))/(1080/4*4/8))+1;


                touchYGridEnd=((touchY-intValue(ht / 3.5))/(patternW/2));
                touchXGridEnd=touchX/(patternW/2);

                if((Math.abs(touchXGridStart-touchXGridEnd)==1)||(Math.abs(touchYGridStart-touchYGridEnd)==1))
                {
                    if((Math.abs(touchXGridStart-touchXGridEnd)==1)&&(Math.abs(touchYGridStart-touchYGridEnd)!=1))
                    {
                        if(touchXGridStart<touchXGridEnd)
                        {
                            Tile tempTile=gridTiles[touchXGridEnd][touchYGridEnd];
                            gridTiles[touchXGridEnd][touchYGridEnd]=gridTiles[touchXGridStart][touchYGridStart];
                            gridTiles[touchXGridStart][touchYGridStart]=tempTile;
                        }

                    }
                }
                invalidate();
            }
```

Comment: Have you checked that the inner part of the if statement executes? Have you checked that `onDraw()` gets called again after the call to `moveBlockOnGrid()`?

Comment: Also, you never initialize the variables in `moveBlockOnGrid()`.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do in `moveBlockOnGrid)`?

Comment: oops i deleted some code but added it back just now. basically moveBlockOnGrid() is supposed to switch the places of two tiles. this part only shift the one you click on and the one to the right. figured the other 4 weren't necessary since the are the same thing with some variables changed. onDraw() definetely gets called again

Comment: Does execution reach the inner part of the nested if statements?

Comment: yes, ive verified this with some System.out.prints. also made sure values changed

Comment: So the tiles change in `moveBlockOnGrid()`. Are the changes visible in `onDraw()`?

Comment: nope. thats my problem. i can see the values when i print them to the console but nothing happens on screen. page updates when i call invalidate (i even put the invalidate inside the if() block, and everything else updated).

Comment: One more suggestion: check that you are accessing the same instances of `gridTiles` in both places. This can be verified by looking at the object id in the debugger.

Comment: it is indeed the same instance of gridtiles.... ugh, i got hopeful for a second...

Comment: I find when I get stuck with a problem like this that it is helpful to create a new Android project that illustrates what is happening. This helps cut out all the cruft in the real app that has nothing to do with the problem I'm trying to solve. In this case, you might want to start with an app that has 2 tiles and then swaps them after a touch event.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your logic properly of moveBlockOnGrid().
but for refreshing view you can use postInvalidate() method.

Make sure your data is being updated in moveBlockOnGrid()

Comment: This is not an answer and should be posted as a comment.

Comment: the values are indeed being changed to what i want, so the if statements are irrelevant in this case. also postInvalidate() did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but I see a change that can make your logic in `moveBlockOnGrid()` more readable. From what I understand, you can only swap blocks which are vertical or horizontal "neighbors". Assuming that you transform the touch coordinates correctly to grid coordinates, you can do the following comparison:

```
if (x1 - x2 == 0 and abs(y1-y2) == 1) or (y1 - y2 == 0 and abs(x1-x2) = 1)
```

This just says that the difference in the x or y coordinates must be 1 and the difference in the opposite direction must be 0.

Comment: thanks for this code-apprentice. really trying to figure out what i did wrong though